# give me a hand to understand this code

Tags: c

i have to write a c code that finds minimum of an array using recursion.i found this in the internet, but  i don't understand it very well, can someone help me understand it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[100],i;
void read(int i,int n)
{
    if(i>=n)
        return;
     printf("element %d",i);
     scanf("%d",&a[i]);
     read(i+1,n);
}

int rec(int a[],int n)
{
    int min;

    if(n==1)
        return a[0];
    else {
        min=rec(a,n-1);

        if(min<a[n-1])
            return min;
        else
            return a[n-1];
    }
} 

void main()
{
    int i,j,n,a[100];
    printf("enter n :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    read(0,n);

    printf("\n%d",rec(a,n));

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand? *I don't understand it very well* is unclear.

Comment: i don't understand the second recursive function

Comment: Its an dreadful algorithm guaranteed to spiral into undefined behavior if you pass `n = 0` for the initial invoke. `n` should be an unsigned type and checked correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if **n=1**, then min. is a[0] as there is only one element.

if **n>1**, then it is calling rec with the array and n-1 as the length each time. So, there will be a time when n=1 and returns a[0]. Then it will compare a[0] with a[1]. And return the minimum. Then it will compare the returned value minimum with a[2] and return the smaller value....and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
int rec(int a[],int n)
{
    int min;

    if(n==1)
        return a[0];
    else {
        min=rec(a,n-1);

        if(min<a[n-1])
            return min;
        else
            return a[n-1];
    }
}
```

This function will go through all of your array elements, then compare them one by one, and each time return the smaller one, giving you the minimum of your array :

example : for a = {10,2,4,5}

- rec will start from 5 and just calls itself with the previous elem until he's at the first : 10
- then will return 10
- will compare 10 with 2 and return 2 because 2 < 10
- will compare 2 with 4 and return 2 because 2 < 4
- will compare 2 with 5 and return 2 because 2 < 5

Comment: why does rec start from 5?

Answer (score 0):

It calculates the minimal value in the array. Look at it that way:
Suppose you're given an array with 10 numbers. A magician tells you the the minimal value of that last 9 elements is 5. You now take the first element and compare it to 5. if it's smaller you return it, otherwise you return 5. The magician is the recursive call to the array with the last n-1 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`rec(a, n)` return the minimum value in {a[0], ..., a[n-1]}

Now we discuss two cases:

If n = 1, then `rec(a,n)` should be `a[0]`, since there is only one value

Otherwise, `rec(a,n)` should be the minimum value of `rec(a,n-1)` (that is, the minimum value in {a[0],..,a[n-2]}) and `a[n-1]`, which is what the following code do:

```
    min=rec(a,n-1);

    if(min<a[n-1])
        return min;
    else
        return a[n-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This program reads a size of an array the user wants to input, next it calls "read" which reads array elements of the given size recursively and fills in global array "a". Next it tries to find a minimal value of the local "a" array using recursive function "rec", that is initialized with garbage by the fact of being of "auto" variable type and types this value to the terminal screen. Next it waits for the user to type any character.